# Process interval tick based on condition RXJS

Tags: merge, rxjs, reactive-programming, angular2-observables

I have the following interval in my code, where I want to run some logic, however I need to do some queries before knowing if I can process the logic developed or not:

```
This is my observable:
const interval$ = Observable.interval(120000).startWith(0);
```

I need to map to this observable and only let it process if the return from a service call is not equal 1:

```
documentRepository.getProcedureLock().then(data => {
                if (data !== null && data !=== '1') {
```

I have tried many things without success... the logic that process my interval is a .mergeMap and I don't have enough experience with it...can u guys help out?

Comment: which should run first? interval or the api?

Comment: `Observable.defer(() => documentRepository.getProcedureLock()).filter(data => data !== null && data !== '1').mergeMapTo(interval$)`

Comment: the api returns a flag that tells if the observable should run or not.

Answer (score 0):

See if that's what u looking for

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(documentRepository.getProcedureLock()).flatMap(data 
=> {
            if (data !== null && data !=== '1') return interval$
// i assume you want data if condition not met
return Rx.Observable.of(data)
}).subscribe(console.log)
```